# To get Result from Task.Run without await

Tags: c#

I have a snippet that looks like this,

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      var res = Task.Run(() => DoTask(param1, param2));
      if(res.IsCompleted)
      { 
          MessageBox.Show("Done");
      }
       MessageBox.Show("DoTask isn't called yet.");
   }
   catch
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Something wrong");
   }
}
```

The `DoTask` method looks like this

```
private async Task<bool> DoTask(int p1, int p2)
{
    // run long tasks   

}
```

I'd want to show `Done` message after the task is done. But this never works. Instead the message `DoTask isn't called yet.` is always called before `DoTask` does tasks.

Comment: Change the signature to `async void` and use `await`. Anything else would just freeze the UI, removing any benefit you'd get from `Task.Run`

Comment: I am wildly guessing you want to do something after task is complete without blocking current thread, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13211334/1997232).

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you are using `Task.Run` when `DoTask` is asynchronous? `Task.Run` should not be required in this case.

Comment: All of the answers posted thus far are dangerously wrong; they all produce situations in which you can easily deadlock your process. You do NOT get a result from a task without `await` *unless you already know that the task has completed*.  Asynchronous tasks **need to be awaited asynchronously**. That's why they are asynchronous!

Answer (score 0):

Panagiotis' answer is the way to go. Should you have the same situation in a method that is not an event handler and you can't use `async` for some reason, here's the next best option:

```cs
Task<bool> task = Task.Run(() => DoTask(param1, param2));
bool res = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

> To get Result from Task.Run without await

The proper way to get a result from an asynchronous task *is* to use `await`:

```
private async void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      var res = await Task.Run(() => DoTask(param1, param2));
      if(res)
      { 
          MessageBox.Show("Done");
      }
       MessageBox.Show("DoTask isn't called yet.");
   }
   catch
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Something wrong");
   }
}
```

Note that [you should *usually* avoid `async void`, but since this code is an event handler, the `async void` is OK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).

Answer (score -2):

Simple Way:

```
bool result = DoTask(paran1, param2).Result;
```

No need to use Task.Run(). But you can use it in the following way (BAD WAY):

```
bool result = Task.Run(() => DoTask(paran1, param2).Result).Result;
```

Comment: Do not follow the advice in this answer. This causes deadlocks.