# C# - Breakpoint not hit or compile error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'`

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I am calling a function that returns Task.

```
Task<string> functionResult = ExecuteAsync(id, key).Wait();
```

then my `ExecuteAsync` method looks like,

```
public async Task<string> ExecuteAsync(int id ,string key)
{

return string myApiEndPoint = await GetMyApiEndpoint(url, key);

}
```

Why can't I use Wait() for ExecuteAsync()?

Also, I tried,

```
Task<string> functionResult = ExecuteAsync(id, key);
Task.WaitAll(functionResult);
```

But, in that case, it doesn't even hit the breakpoint in ExecuteAsync method return statement.

Comment: `Wait` returns `void`, i.e. nothing.

Comment: string functionResult = await ExecuteAsync(id, key); Is what you are looking for. No .Wait() needed, which then makes your functionResult type string.

Comment: Have you tried it without the `.Wait()`? If it's simply returning a `Task<>` you shouldn't need the `.Wait()`.

Comment: @AnthonyG. But, my parent method is not marked async, and I can't mark it async. What should I do in that case?

Comment: @ahwm Yeah, with that the breakpoint doesn't hit `return string myApiEndPoint = await GetMyApiEndpoint(url, key);
` So nothing get's called

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0mcYVxJEl0 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTKGRJy5P2M have some great explanations

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211334/how-do-i-wait-until-task-is-finished-in-c the answer posted here shows how to use ContinueWith and Wait.

Comment: The breakpoint doesn't hit it because that code doesn't compile, so anything you're running is an obsolete version that doesn't match the source you're looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for any reason you don't want or can't use the async method you can always use:

```
string functionResult = ExecuteAsync(id, key).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

But have in mind that it may cause a deadlock.

Comment: Actually this code worked, `Task<string> functionResult = Task.Run(async () => ExecuteSave(id, key).GetAwaiter().GetResult());` Slight modification from your answer.